# Merge highlighting snippets with corresponding documents

Tags: solr, solr4

While using highlighting we get output in 2 sections.

```
<result name="response" numFound="2345" start="0">
<doc>...</doc>
<doc>...</doc>
</result>

<lst name="highlighting">
<lst name="08dcc4e3">...highlighted fields with <em> tag...</lst>
<lst name="12e47c63">...highlighted fields with <em> tag...</lst>
</lst>
```

Is it possible to have 'em' tags within the fields inside the documents?
For example if query is for 'engine', I should get something like -

```
<doc>
<str name="content">
Build your own search <em>engine</em> using solr
</str>
.
.
.
</doc>
```

If the above thing is not possible, is it possible to have highlighting output of document id xyz inside the document with other fields, something like -

```
<doc>
<str name="id">xyz</str>
.
.
.
<lst name="highlighting">
<arr name="content">
<str>...</str>
</arr>
</lst>
</doc>
```

If this is not possible with simple config changes and default highlighting, Is it possible with custom highlighting module (by extending default highlighting or so).

I am currently using solr 3.4 but let me know if it is possible in solr versions post 3.4